# Using unittest.mock.patch.dict on os.environ is resulting in a TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm trying to mock out `os.environ` in a Python unit test with `unittest.mock.patch.dict`. However, when I try to execute the test, I'm getting `TypeError: str expected, not int`.

Roughly, I have the following:

```
import os
from unittest.mock import patch
with patch.dict('os.environ', values={"foo": 3, "bar": "hello"}, clear=True):
    print(os.environ["foo"])
    print(os.environ["bar"])
```

Executing this code yields the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 1630, in __enter__
    self._patch_dict()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 1652, in _patch_dict
    in_dict.update(values)
  File "/Users/<redacted>/<redeacted>/<redacted>/venv/bin/../lib/python3.7/_collections_abc.py", line 841, in update
    self[key] = other[key]
  File "/Users/<redacted>/<redacted>/<redacted>/venv/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 683, in __setitem__
    value = self.encodevalue(value)
  File "/Users/<redacted>/<redacted>/<redacted>/venv/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 753, in encode
    raise TypeError("str expected, not %s" % type(value).__name__)
TypeError: str expected, not int
```

What am I doing wrong? I've looked up the documentation and it seems like this is the correct way to use `unittest.mock.patch` to mock a dictionary. I'm running Python 3.7.0 on MacOS High Sierra (version 10.13.5).

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that `os.environ` [checks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/88bfd0bce05043f658e50addd21366f317995e35/Lib/os.py#L747) to see that the value you're setting is of type `str`. In my case, changing `values` to `{"foo": "3", "bar": "hello"}` fixed the problem.